# pm2 starting my node js script in fork_mode

Tags: node.js, pm2

Hello Stackoverflow Coders, I have 3 node js script with 3 different port numbers on my web hosting account.

Am using PM2 to start the node js script.
 I have succeded in starting two script using pm2
For example

```
pm2 start script1.js

pm2 start script2.js
```

the script1.js and script2. js were assigned id 0 and 1 respectively.

but when i tried to start sccript 3, it says

```
[PM2] Starting /server/script3.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
```

please what could be the issue. how do i start the third script since its port number is different...

Thanks

Comment: Can you show code in script3.js. May be you have a cluster implementation inside?

Comment: are you sure all have different ports? Please share your all 3 scripts code